# Overlap of Elements in d3.js Word cloud

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am trying to create a word cloud in d3. I have the following code

> http://jsbin.com/vefifukeno/edit?html,js,output

How can i overcome the overlap of words. I am unable to understand why the words go out of margin as i have given Math.random() it should be between 0 and 1.

Answer (score 1):

Please Note that in Jason Davies himself wrote : 
"Note that this is the only the layout algorithm and any code for converting text into words and rendering the final output requires additional development."
  https://www.jasondavies.com/wordcloud/about/

So you must implement it by your self..